# Why does Shri Goswami Tulsidasji Maharaj write that Sri Hari is different from Vishnu?

Tags: scripture, vishnu, ramayana, rama, ramcharitmanas

The following Doha says that Manu and Satarupa performed penance to attain Shri Hari, from whom occurs many Shivas, Bhramas, and Vishnus. While my understanding is that 'Hari' is used for 'Vishnu'; hence they are the same and not different. Even in other parts of Ramcharitmanas 'Sri Hari' is used for 'Vishnu', that is why I am a bit confused on the Doha.

[image: Doha from Ramcharitmanas Geetapress Gorkahpur English Edition]

Comment: Yeah.. here Hari is being used for Brahmn (or the MahaVishnu).. Actually, Ramcharitmans tells the story of the kalpa where Mahavishnu becomes Ram and Mahalaxmi becomes Sita.. so you will see similar lines at many places…though at some places it’s interchangeably used for Vishnu.. It’s Kavya so same word have diff meanings based on context

Comment: Shri hari or Shriman narayana is used for parabrahma, as there are many bhu lokas and each having its trimurti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hari (**हरि:- क्लेश हरति इति हरि**)

Meaning:- one who destroys/takes over difficulties.

In Ramcharitmanas, hari word signifies parabrahman maha Vishnu swarup shri ram

As padma Purana says:-

**ब्रह्माविष्णुमहेशाद्याः यस्या अंश लोक साधकाः।
तम् आदिदेवं रामं विशुद्धं परमं भजे।।**

Quoted in gita press Kalyan ank.

Crores of Brahma , Vishnu, Shiva and other devas are whose ansh, I salute to that adideva bhagwan shri Ramchandra.

And skand Puran Nirvana khand says:-

**यदैकमात्मानमनेकधैव विभज्य विश्वं व्यतनोरमूर्ते ।
तदैवभानोवि रश्मयोऽमी त्वत्तोवयं रामविनिस्सृता हि॥**

(Skandh Puran Nirvaan Khand)

Lord Sri Vishnu says to Sri Ram:—

O Sri Ram! At the time when you expand the world by dividing your one form into many forms, at that time we emerge from you just as rays are transmitted from the sun.

**यस्यांशेन एव ब्रह्म विष्णु महेश्वरा अपि जाता महाविष्णुर्य्यस्य दिव्यगुणाश्च ।
स एव कार्यकारणयोः परः परमपुरुषो रामो दाशरथिर्वभुव॥**

~Atharvavedā Shrüti Vedsaropanishad

Whose Ansh are Brahma Visnu and Mahesvara(Rudra), Whose divine Guna is Mahavisnu, The only one who is the cause of all causes, The one who is higher than the highest, such is Śrī Rāma, the son of Dasratha
.
So, goswami tulsidas ji words were never wrong

I hope, my answer will you guys